# Code to get Content Root of the PyCharm project

Tags: python

Is there any way to get the Content Root address of a PyCharm project inside our code? I need to open the file from another package of the same project, and cannot provide proper addressing.

Comment: you can reference using './folder_name'

Comment: What about when you maybe deploy this code elsewhere with no IDE? What if someone isn't using Pycharm? My point is that Pycharm shouldn't matter... You should be using the absolute path to the current script, and move to paths from there

Comment: What you tried? Please show your effort first.

Comment: @Gokul C No, "./folder_name/file" did not work for me

Comment: @ cricket_007: I tried to do that, but it seems that there is no way rather than decoupling the string version of the file path, removing the sub-directories, and coupling it back agian. I did not want to deal with string conversions, I beleive there should be an easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could code a function that given the project name returns the path to the root of the project. I am sharing this here for further use:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path  

def path_to_project_root(project_name):
        path = os.getcwd()
        while not str(path).endswith(project_name):
            path = Path(path).parent

        print(path)
        return path
```

Comment: Not working for me : it searches in the root directory of the filesystem (path='/') indefinitely. I have to stop the process manually.